# iOS: Recording from two AVCaptureSessions is out of sync

Tags: ios, swift, video, camera, avfoundation

I'm trying to record Video from one `AVCaptureSession`, and Audio from another `AVCaptureSession`.

The reason I'm using two separate capture sessions is because I want to disable and enable the Audio one on the fly without interrupting the Video session.

I believe Snapchat and Instagram also use this approach, as background music keeps playing when you open the Camera, and only slightly stutters (caused by the `AVAudioSession.setCategory(..)` call) once you start recording.

However I couldn't manage to synchronize the two `AVCaptureSession`s, and whenever I try to record `CMSampleBuffer`s into an `AVAssetWriter`, the video and audio frames are out of sync.

Here's a quick YouTube video showcasing the offset: https://youtube.com/shorts/jF1arThiALc

I notice two bugs:

1. The video and audio tracks are out of sync - video frames start almost a second before the first audio sample starts to be played back, and towards the end the delay is also noticeable because the video stops / freezes while the audio continues to play.
2. The video contains frames from BEFORE I even pressed startRecording(), as if my iPhone had a time machine!

I am not sure how the second one can even happen, so at this point I'm asking for help if anyone has any experience with that.

Roughly my code:

```swift
let videoCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
let audioCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()

func setup() {
  // ...adding videoCaptureSession outputs (AVCaptureVideoDataOutput)
  // ...adding audioCaptureSession outputs (AVCaptureAudioDataOutput)
  videoCaptureSession.startRunning()
}

func startRecording() {
  self.assetWriter = AVAssetWriter(outputURL: tempURL, fileType: .mov)
  self.videoWriter = AVAssetWriterInput(...)
  assetWriter.add(videoWriter)
  self.audioWriter = AVAssetWriterInput(...)
  assetWriter.add(audioWriter)

  AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.mixWithOthers, .defaultToSpeaker])
  audioCaptureSession.startRunning() // <-- lazy start that
}

func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from _: AVCaptureConnection) {
  // Record Video Frame/Audio Sample to File in custom `RecordingSession` (AVAssetWriter)
  if isRecording {
    switch captureOutput {
    case is AVCaptureVideoDataOutput:
      self.videoWriter.append(sampleBuffer)
    case is AVCaptureAudioDataOutput:
      // TODO: Do I need to update the PresentationTimestamp here to synchronize it to the other capture session? or not?
      self.audioWriter.append(sampleBuffer)
    default:
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Full code here:

1. [Video Capture Session Configuration](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/ccb04016a0fbe1188b7ff6798df5d64099f458fc/package/ios/Core/CameraSession%2BConfiguration.swift#L15-L150)
2. [Audio Capture Session Configuration](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/ccb04016a0fbe1188b7ff6798df5d64099f458fc/package/ios/Core/CameraSession%2BConfiguration.swift#L304-L359)
3. Later on, [startRecording() call](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/ccb04016a0fbe1188b7ff6798df5d64099f458fc/package/ios/Core/CameraSession%2BVideo.swift#L14-L146)
4. [RecordingSession, my `AVAssetWriter` abstraction](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/main/package/ios/Core/RecordingSession.swift)
5. [Audio Session activation](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/ccb04016a0fbe1188b7ff6798df5d64099f458fc/package/ios/Core/CameraSession%2BAudio.swift#L13-L53)
6. And finally, [writing the `CMSampleBuffer`s](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/ccb04016a0fbe1188b7ff6798df5d64099f458fc/package/ios/Core/CameraSession.swift#L257-L285)

Comment: couldn't you use a single session and keep background music by configuring your audio session to use `.mixWithOthers`?

Comment: @GordonChilds yea I had that before - the problem with using a single capture session is that there is a mini stutter in the background audio once you configure a session with .mixWithOthers. It is only for a sub-second, but it is annoying if that's playing everytime you open the Camera even if you're not intending on recording anything with it. See my post from 2 years ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67807394

Comment: ...and my goal was to delay that mini stutter in the background audio to as late as possible - which is once the user actually hits start recording. Snapchat and Instagram also achieve that, I'm not quite sure how but I notice that mini stutter only once I start recording, not when I just open the Camera. They also don't have the delay nor the out of sync issues that I'm experiencing, haha

Comment: When you say "sync" do you mean the audio happens at different times to the video? (it's hard to tell in your sample videos) or that the a/v start and end at different times? If the latter, even a single `AVCaptureSession` will have that property, perhaps in a less obvious way, so you have to decide which sample buffers to include in and exclude from the recording  based on their timestamps.

Comment: Well the weird thing is that it records video frames from even half a second before I pressed down on the record button, which I don't even understand how that could be possible since the AVAssetWriter instance doesn't even exist beforehand... When I film a timer and start filming at e.g. 5:00, the actual video contains frames starting at 4:23, almost a second beforehand! And the audio is missing until it hits 5:00, then audio starts.

Comment: @GordonChilds check this out, I uploaded a screen recording on how it looks in the app, and the resulting video. I think the out of sync issue should be clearly visible here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FnVZQeoz5E-34A2o1SsdDfWE0O24zo0T?usp=share_link

Comment: Oh my god I figured out what the culprit was! I am using .cinematicExtended video stabilization, which introduces a 1-2s delay for CMSampleBuffers! Now I just need to figure out how to synchronize that and wait for late buffers in my AVAssetWriter...

Comment: Thanks for your help @GordonChilds, I found the issue - I was not properly accounting for the Presentation Timestamps! See my answer

Comment: Fascinating. Trust the timestamps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my god, I finally found the culprit.

The Video Stabilization mode `cinematicExtended` actually caused a huge delay in the Video Pipeline because it keeps an internal buffer of frames to stabilize them. This just takes time. Apparently this takes up to 1 second on my modern iPhone 15 Pro.
The way my `RecordingSession` was designed is that I just wrote the Video and Audio buffers to the session once I received them, and I used their presentation timestamps as the timestamp for the video.

What I didn't account for here was that the presentation timestamp is not the same value as the current time, the frame might be older and we just got it after it has went through a bunch of processing (stabilization)!

E.g. relative to the timer we see on screen - when I start recording, the time is 5:00, but the first frame that actually arrives at 5:00 still has a presentation timestamp of 3:86, because that's when it was captured from the Camera.
The mistake I previously made here was that we wrote this Frame to the file - which I shouldn't do, it's from the past!

This PR fixes that behaviour and only writes Frames to the file that have a presentation timestamp later than when we actually started recording, so the first frame that should've been written to the file was the one with the presentation timestamp 5:00, which might come in when the current time is already 6:86, so it's 1:86 seconds too late.

Here's my PR with code which fixes the issue: https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/pull/2206

What a funny bug, I was pulling my hairs out on this one.